# can we automatically update client secret in azure active directory application?

Tags: azure, azure-activedirectory

There is an application (inside Azure active directory--> app registration) in my project. The client secret in in that application in “certification and secrets” has got expired now. Now I want to update the secret periodically (automatically) instead of feeding it manually after it expires.

I googled a lot but all I can find is to create automation accounts for Resource groups, but,  in my case I want to automate the secrets for AAD applications and not for Resource group

Can you please guide me on this issue?